# How to Open Folder in Internal Storage from Android App programmatically?

Tags: android-intent, intentfilter, android-file, motorola-droid

How to open Folder in Internal storage of phone in Android programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
File folderDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/foldername/");

File[] listFiles = fileDirectory.listFiles();

if (listFiles.length != 0) {
    
    for (int indx = 0; indx < listFiles.length; indx++) {
        String fileName = listFiles[indx].toString();
        System.out.println(fileName); 
    }
}
```